# Rails: restore ActiveRecord object encoded with to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model called Account with these associations:

```
has_many :contracts, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :packages, :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :contracts
accepts_nested_attributes_for :packages
```

Before destroying any Account object i save it on a file with to_json:

```
@account.to_json(:include => [:packages, :contracts])
```

Fine. The problem happens when i try to restore it ( on another script ):

```
account_data = JSON.parse json
@account = Account.new account_data
```

This raises an exception:

```
Package(#70193553579560) expected, got Hash(#70193548333800)
```

Why this happens? Shouldn't Rails accept a hash in this case?

Will i have to remove contracts and packages keys from Hash and insert them after i do @account.save? I'm looking for a cleaner way to handle this :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the output of `@account.to_json(:include => [:packages, :contracts])`.  It serializes the associations as JSON, so you end up with something like:

```
{"id":10, packages:[{id:5,description:"Package1"}], contracts:[]}
```

When you try to reload the JSON, under the hood it's trying to do this:

```
account.packages = [{id:5,description:"Package1"}]
```

This doesn't work because account.packages is an association, and you can't build it directly using a Hash.  You can, however, pass the Hash as nested attributes:

```
account.packages_attributes = [{id:5,description:"Package1"}]
```

`packages_attributes` is a method defined by the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` class method, which you already have in your model.

This is not going to play nicely with `to_json`.  However, ActiveRecord also has a `from_json` method that is designed to play nicely to `to_json`